# How to use own RGB value to change Winform Button ForeColor?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

How can I change the Buttons's ForeColor with my own RGB value (example: 131;160;21) programmatically (not from designer)? The property R, G and B in Button-control are only "get" property and not "set".

I want to change it when the "Enabled" property is changed and I have also implemented event handler for EnabledChanged event.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) Method

```
MyButton.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255);
```

If you need to control the alpha too, use the [overloaded method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for long delay. Yes this works. THANK YOU very much. Problem solved.

Comment: Please mark at is answer by clicking the green arrow next to this question :)